# iterate through string to get match object from the List in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have tried this below code, It should display "Match". But Somehow it isn't.

```
set mylist to {"wade", "lee"}
set username to "sarawade"
set a to (count username)

repeat a times
    set mystring to do shell script "echo " & username & " | sed 's/[a-z]//'"
    set username to mystring
    display dialog username
    repeat with theitem in mylist
        if username = theitem then
            display dialog "Match"
        end if
    end repeat
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare **username** with **theitem**, which is a **reference** to list's element. You should compare to **contents** of theitem instead:

```
set mylist to {"wade", "lee"}
set username to "sarawade"
set a to (count username)

repeat a times
    set mystring to do shell script "echo " & username & " | sed 's/[a-z]//'"
    set username to mystring
    display dialog username
    repeat with theitem in mylist
        if username = contents of theitem then -- EDITED
            display dialog "Match"
        end if
    end repeat
end repeat
```

NOTE: you can do it easy:

```
set mylist to {"wade", "lee"}
set username to "sarawade"

display dialog username with title "The username"

set matchFound to false
repeat with theitem in mylist
    if username ends with (contents of theitem) then
        set matchFound to true
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

if matchFound then
    return contents of theitem
else
    return "No match found"
end if
```

Comment: what is the difference between "theitem" and "contents of theitem" ?

Comment: **theItem** is a reference, that is **address of 1st byte** of list's element in the RAM. The **contents** is what is stored at this address beginning from this first byte. AppleScript doesn't provide addresses in numerical form for security reasons. It provides instead the **reference** like this: **item 1 of {"wade", "lee"}**. The **contents** of this reference is text **"wade"**.

Comment: Ok, One more thing. How can I get out of the loop (equivalent to break the loop) once "Match Founded" ?

Comment: add **exit repeat** after display dialog code line

Comment: Already done that, I think apart from this, one more exit repeat required. I just want to stop all the loops once I got  the "Match Founded" message.

Comment: You can, of course, double-exit nested loops using a "semaphore" variable, but users here will scold me if I do this, because here you can get by with the 1 repeat loop, as in the 2nd script of my answer. Just replace **return contents of theitem** with **exit repeat**.

Comment: I edited the 2nd script of my answer for you. Try it now.

Comment: Nice answer. +⒈  Two quick notes: the reason list items are referenced has nothing to do with security—it's because it's faster to operate on list items by reference than it would be by value.  Also, whilst your advice regarding `contents of...` was spot on—and it _is_ the reason the OP's attempt didn't work—your script would work just fine with: `if username ends with the item then...`.